# Trocar a indentação de TAB para espaços no Vim

Tags: vim

Tenho um projeto em que alguns arquivos estão indentados com `tab` e outros com 4 espaços. Existe algum modo no Vim de reindentar todos os arquivos para 4 espaços?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um modo é usar o  `:set expandtab`
para definir o número de espaços é possível usar `:set tabstop=4`
depois use o comando `:retab` para converter o arquivo.

Comment: Complementando, você pode usar `:argdo retab | update` para fazer pra todos os arquivos abertos.

Answer (score 1):

Para alterar em todas as linhas:

```
:%s/\t/    /g
```

Ou, se vc quiser alterar apenas na linha atual:

```
:s/\t/    /g
```